# How to pause and unpause my program on the desired key

Tags: c++

My program makes simple movements with the mouse, I use c++, it works through the console, I would like to pause on the ''0x32, 0x33, 0x34'' key and make it work again on the ''0x31'' key

```
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE) < 0) {
            if (!is_mouse_down) {
                is_mouse_down = true;
                if (gun != nullptr)
                    gun_index = 0;
            }
            if (gun != nullptr && gun_index != gun->len) {
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, long(gun->pattner[gun_index][0] * K), long(gun->pattner[gun_index][1] * K), 0, 0);
                ++gun_index;
                Sleep(gun_delay);
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
            is_mouse_down = false;

        Sleep(150);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: ready, look my code now

Comment: Are you asking how to capture keypress events or how to gracefully pause your infinite loop?

Comment: I would like to pause on the ''0x32, 0x33, 0x34'' key and make it work again on the ''0x31'' key